# Manipulating IEEE-754 floating-point encodings

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

```
/* 
 * float_twice - Return bit-level equivalent of expression 2*f for
 *   floating point argument f.
 *   Both the argument and result are passed as unsigned int's, but
 *   they are to be interpreted as the bit-level representation of
 *   single-precision floating point values.
 *   When argument is NaN, return argument
 *   Legal ops: Any integer/unsigned operations incl. ||, &&. also if, while
 *   Max ops: 30
 *   Rating: 4
 */

    unsigned float_twice(unsigned f)
    {
            unsigned sign = f >> 31;
            unsigned exp = (f >> 23) & 0xFF;
            unsigned frac = f & 0x7FFFFF;

            /* NaN, +oo, -oo */
            if (exp == 0xFF)
                    return f;

            if (exp == 0xFE) {
                    exp = 0xFF;
                    frac = 0;
            } else if (exp > 0) {
                    exp++;
            } else /* exp == 0 */ {
                    if ((frac & 0x400000) == 0x400000) {
                            exp = 1;
                            frac = (frac << 1) & 0x7FFFFF;
                    } else {
                            frac <<= 1;
                    }
            }

            return (sign << 31) | (exp << 23) | frac;
    }
```

In the above code, look at the last else part.

1. In the denormalized form, it checks the MSB of the fraction before shifting left by one.
2. If the MSB is 1 then the code sets the exponent to 1.
3. Shouldn't the the value for exp be = 127 +1? ( where 127 is the bias for floating point)

Comment: Look at the true exponent of the smallest normalized `binary32` number. It is -126. The biased exponent to be stored in the `binary32` exponent field therefore is  -126 + 127 = 1.

Comment: 127 is the bias for _normal_ floating point values.

Answer (score 2):

The `exp` the code is preparing is not the mathematical exponent of the floating-point value. It is the value for the exponent field, which is biased by 127.

For normal numbers, the exponent field ranges from 1 to 254, corresponding to mathematical exponents of −126 to 127.

In the case you ask about, the number is subnormal. Its exponent field is 0 (which also corresponds to a mathematical exponent of −126, the same as an exponent field of 1, because subnormal values are handled specially). To double the number, the code is going to shift the significand left by one bit. If this carries a 1 bit out of the significand, the number becomes normal instead of subnormal. It will then have the lowest exponent of the normal range, which is a 1 in the exponent field, corresponding to a mathematical exponent of −126.